# Time intervals for repeating alarm in AlarmManager are not always as they should be

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I have set a repeating alarm using `AlarmManager` this way:

```
    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmMgr.setRepeating (AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 100, 10000, mPendingIntent);

    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
            sharedPrefsEditor.putString(TIMER_LOG_KEY, sharedPrefs.getString(TIMER_LOG_KEY, "") + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + "|");
            sharedPrefsEditor.commit();
        }
    }, 
    new IntentFilter(ALARM_TEST_TIMER_ACTION));
```

`mPendingIntent` sends a broadcast.

The alarms is supposed to be executed every 10 seconds (= 10,000 ms).

I logged the execution times and found out 2 exceptional intervals: 23 seconds and 143 seconds.

I have to mention that all of the other intervals were good (maximum 11.1 seconds).

Why does this happen? How can I avoid these exceptions?

Comment: What does `mPendingIntent` do? Start an activity? Start a service? Send a broadcast?

Comment: Is your logging code right in the `onReceive()` method?

Comment: Yes, it is. It sets a value in `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: Please post your `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: Note that Android can and will terminate your process at any point when you are not in the foreground. Using `AlarmManager` with a `BroadcastReceiver` set up via `registerReceiver()` is not very realistic. I would switch to your long-term solution of putting the `BroadcastReceiver` in the manifest, switch to using LogCat instead of `SharedPreferences` for logging (so disk I/O considerations do not impact your tests), then run your tests again.

Comment: It is just a test. How I implement my `BroadcastReceiver` does not have to affect the time intervals. You don't answer my question.

Comment: "It is just a test" -- and it is possibly a flawed test. If you do not want to run a better test, that is your decision.